# Use module augmentation conditionally to write a plugin system

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a wrapper library around MongoDB's official node driver and want to include a plugin system inspired from [Dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/tree/dev/src/plugin). The way they handled it there is quite easy:

- A plugin lives under its own folder in the `plugin` folder (and ends up in the same npm package, there is no package per plugin), but the content of `plugin` is not included in the main exports. You have to import it explicitly, apart from `dayjs`. Then by applying it via `dayjs.extend`, this mutates the `Dayjs` class internally to add the desired functionalities. Example:

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import RelativeTime from "dayjs/plugin/relativeTime";
import Duration from "dayjs/plugin/duration";

dayjs.extend(RelativeTime);
dayjs.extend(Duration);
```

I managed to set up something similar pretty easily. The problem is with TypeScript. Here I'm on my own because dayjs' code is in plain JS. They include a `types` folder which contains the type declarations separately.

To illustrate, here is an example: if I import `dayjs/plugin/duration`, TypeScript sees the types in `/types/plugin/duration`, which contains:

```
declare module 'dayjs' {
  interface Dayjs {
    add(duration: plugin.Duration): Dayjs
    subtract(duration: plugin.Duration): Dayjs
  }

  export const duration: plugin.CreateDurationType;
  export function isDuration(d: any): d is plugin.Duration
}
```

This augmentation gets only "applied" if `dayjs/plugin/duration` is imported. This conditional augmentation based on imports is what I don't seem to be able to replicate using a TS-only codebase.

In my project, I have a class called `Mongo` and this class should be extendable via plugins, both with static and instance methods. For example, when I wanted to add a static method `bson` on it, my `plugin/bson/index.ts` would look something like this:

```
const plugin: Plugin = (mongoClass) => {
  mongoClass.bson = () => { ... }
};

export default plugin;

declare module "../../index" {
  namespace Mongo {
    const bson: () => void;
  }
}
```

This works except for the "conditional" augmentation. Even if this file is not included (nor directly nor indirectly through other files), the augmentation is applied by TS. At least in my `index.test.ts` file that lives in the same repo.

Worse: when I try to apply the same augmentation logic not to classes but to functions or variables of my package, it works but then there is a TypeScript error at the place where these functions or variables are defined because of the missing fields that come from the plugins. I believe this is also due to TypeScript not being able to "exclude" files from one another if they don't import themselves.

I have no idea how to setup something like this properly in a package destined for a single NPM publication and I have not found anything on it after hours of research.

How can I achieve this?
If I can't, what alternatives do I have? Are there better plugin patterns for the TS world (if possible avoiding having to publish multiple packages)?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

You need to publish multiple type files for each "entry" of your package.

Typescript will look for a type definition file with the same name as the file you are importing but with a `d.ts` extension. You can read about this [classic resolution here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#classic).

For example, you have your main entry and its types and then every single plugin and its type.

Your `package.json` may look something like this:

```
{
   "name": "my-package",
   "main": "index.js",
   "types": "index.d.ts"
}
```

Your project structure for publishing looks like this:

```
- index.js
- index.d.ts
- plugins/
  - my-plugin/
    - index.js
    - index.d.ts
  - other-plugin/
    - index.js
    - index.d.ts
```

`index.js` is your compiled main entry project (possibly a bundle of all main project files excluding plugins). `index.d.ts` contains the types for your main entry.

`plugins/my-plugin/index.js` is your compiled plugin entry. `plugins/my-plugin/index.d.ts` is where the types for this plugin will be automatically imported by Typescript.

The plugins type file is where you can use `declare module` and overwrite the interface for your main entry / module. Typescript will auto import these type definition when someone imports your plugin via `import myPlugin from 'your-package/plugins/my-plugin';`.

---

### Option 2

Another option is to use the [new `exports` field inside `package.json`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) which will let you specify specific paths and mappings for your package entries and types. This uses [node's resolutions strategy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node) for finding types.

```
// package.json
{
    "name": "my-package",
    "type": "module",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            // Entry-point for `import "my-package"` in ESM
            "import": {
                // Where TypeScript will look.
                "types": "./types/esm/index.d.ts",
                // Where Node.js will look.
                "default": "./esm/index.js"
            }
        },
        "my-plugin": {
           // Entry-point for `import myPlugin from "my-package/my-plugin"` in ESM
           "import": {
               // Where Typescript will look.
               "types": "./dist/my-plugin/index.d.ts",
               // Where Node.js will look.
               "default": "./dist/my-plugin/index.js"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you fine grain control as you don't have to colocate your type definition files with your JS files (they can be completely different paths/dirs).  However, be warned, that **all entries** must be defined this way as this disables typical path access to your package `import 'my-package/random-file.js` will no longer work unless you create the mapping inside `package.json` `exports` field.

This is the tradeoff with this approach. It can be cumbersome to maintain if you are going to have many plugins and many different entries. If you are going to do this, I recommend automating the creation of these exports using some custom Node.js script before publishing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How does this work in the ts source files? How should the plugin and the test files import the package itself? The augmentation that I put in these TS files gets applied globally to all files, and thus throws TS errors in the main library files.